# ODBC Command Procedure Function Expects Parameters

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2016

The stored procedure in SQL works perfectly with the desired result.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[My_StoredProc]
    (@autoidx int,
     @r varchar(max) OUTPUT)
--with encryption
AS
BEGIN
    -- ... some code here ...
END
```

Trying to call the stored procedure in VS 2019 using ODBC command but I get getting an error :

> Procedure or function My_StoredProc expects parameter @autoidx, which was not supplied.

My code:

```
string connectionString = String.Format("DSN={0};uid=my_user;pwd=my_pwd", toolStripComboBoxDSN.Text);

// OdbcCommand DbCommand = new OdbcCommand("My_StoredProc", DbConnection);
// DbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
//DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@autoidx",  this.AutoIndex); //this.AutoIndex has value


//DbCommand.Parameters.Add("@r", OdbcType.VarChar,500);
//DbCommand.Parameters["@r"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
//DbConnection.Open();
//DbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
//string s = (string)DbCommand.Parameters["@r"].Value;


//Code below is working. With a major change in CommandType 

OdbcCommand DbCommand = new OdbcCommand("  EXEC dbo.My_StoredProc @autoidx=?  ", DbConnection);
DbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

DbCommand.Parameters.Add("?", OdbcType.Int).Value = this.AutoIndex;

DbConnection.Open();
var s = DbCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4583460) - 13.0.5103.6 (X64) 
 Nov  1 2020 00:13:28 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19042: )


string connectionString = String.Format("DSN={0};uid=my_user;pwd=my_pwd", toolStripComboBoxDSN.Text);

Comment: For a start don't use AddWithValue - its bad.

Comment: The link - [don't use addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). FWIW - a comment containing some code that builds a connection string is not particularly useful if the content of that string is important.

Comment: `Add("@r", OdbcType.VarChar,500);` Sure hope that returned value never gets near the 2gb possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had one opinion:

1.- Try to change this

```
DbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@autoidx",  this.AutoIndex);
```

for this:

```
DbCommand.Parameters.Add("@autoidx",  SqlDbType.Int);
DbCommand.Parameters["@autoidx"].Value = this.AutoIndex;
```

2.- Check you DbConnection, sometimes this contain other database for example db_developer instead of db_production.

Comment: The connection string is public in the class and working fine using a parameterize SELECT statement and pointing to the right database . 

`DbCommand.Parameters.Add("@autoidx",  SqlDbType.Int);
DbCommand.Parameters["@autoidx"].Value = this.AutoIndex;`

same error

Comment: ok, now try to change including the schema of the data base with the stored procedure: OdbcCommand DbCommand = new OdbcCommand("dbo.My_StoredProc", DbConnection);

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `System.Data.SqlClient` *native* SQL client to SQL Server, and use proper `using` blocks and proper parameter definition - something like this:

```
// standard SQL Client connection string
string connectionString = "......";

// define connection and command in proper "usinh" blocks
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.My_StoredProc", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // define parameters properly
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@autoidx", SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@r", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    
    // set values to parametesr
    cmd.Parameters["@autoidx"] = this.AutoIndex;
    
    // open connection, execute procedure, close connection
    conn.Open();
    
    int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    string s = cmd.Parameters["@r"].Value?.ToString();
    
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Couple of minor points: because the Dispose() closes an open connection, you don't really need conn.Close() at the end; secondly, it is slightly more efficient to set the value of the parameter when creating it.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock: agreed - `conn.Close()` is not *absolutely* necessary - but I just still like to do it myself, explicitly - then it's done right now - not "somewhen later" ....